# Extract lines that contains a number listed in another file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a list of IDs and sentences `sentences.txt` such as:

```
11771_12317_000143  traite exactement ses invités comme un commissaire priseur ses marchandises elle explique les manies et coutumes de chacun mais oublie naturellement tout ce qui pourrait vous intéresser au personnage pauvre lady brandon vous êtes
11772_12317_000144  dont je ne lui ai jamais parlé il n'en sait rien il l'ignorera toujours mais le monde peut la deviner et je ne veux pas découvrir mon âme aux bas regards quêteurs mon cœur ne sera jamais mis sous un microscope il y a trop de moi-même dans cette chose harry trop de moi
11772_12317_000145  emplissons l'esprit d'un fatras de faits dans l'espérance niaise de garder notre place l'homme bien informé voilà le moderne idéal le cerveau de cet homme bien informé est une chose étonnante c'est comme la boutique d'un
```

And a list of numbers `numbers.txt` such as:

```
10082
10620
10827
11771
11247
115
```

I want to extract all lines from the first file that contain one (or several) of the numbers listed in the second file. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep --file numbers.txt sentences.txt
```

However, bear in mind that items like:

```
123
```

will match items like:

```
11772_12317_000145
```